# Error while running Eclipse Phonegap

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, visual-studio-debugging

I have created a simple application in android [PhoneGap] [Eclipse] {Sorry for this convention because I am a .NET developer and I don't know how to explain that I am developing android application on eclipse}

When I am running the application I am getting the below error. No matter what I click it closes my simulator, please help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the same by going to

```
Visual Studio 2005 > Tools > Option > Debugging > Just-In-Time
```

I have disabled all three checkboxes

1. Managed
2. Native
3. Script

But I am little curious to know if it affect my .NET compilation.